# How to Check byte array empty or not?

Tags: c#

I am downloading the word file for `GetSourceAttachment` method. When this method returns empty bytes then my byte `Attachment` array gives an error:

> Object reference not set instance of object

It gives the error when I check the length of `Attachment` in `if` condition.

Can any one help me to default initialize the byte array, then check the length?

```
try
{
        byte[] Attachment = null ;

        string Extension = string.Empty;
        ClsPortalManager objPortalManager = new ClsPortalManager();
        Attachment = objPortalManager.GetSourceAttachment(Convert.ToInt32(hdnSourceId.Value), out Extension);
        if (Attachment.Length > 0 && Attachment != null)
        {
            DownloadAttachment("Attacment", Attachment, Extension);
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "SymbolError", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Attachment is not Uploaded !');</script>");
        }            
}
catch
{

}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Just do

```
if (Attachment != null  && Attachment.Length > 0)
```

From *[&& Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, **but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.**

Answer (score 26):

You must swap the order of your test:

From:

```
if (Attachment.Length > 0 && Attachment != null)
```

To:

```
if (Attachment != null && Attachment.Length > 0 )
```

The first version attempts to dereference `Attachment` first and therefore throws if it's null. The second version will check for nullness first and only go on to check the length if it's not null (due to "boolean short-circuiting").

---

[EDIT] I come from the future to tell you that with later versions of C# you can use a ["null conditional operator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to simplify the code above to:

```
if (Attachment?.Length > 0)
```

Answer (score 21):

**.Net V 4.6 OR C #  6.0**

*Try This*

```
 if (Attachment?.Length > 0)
```

Comment: Maybe in 5 years our systems will recognize it... in my 4.6 framework project it's still compiles as an error.

Comment: @HellBaby then you need to check the language associated with your project. Just because you are using DotNet 4.6 doesn’t mean that you are using C# >= 6. You could still be using C#5 for all you know. Go into your project's settings: right-click on project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced and set the language explicitly to C# >= 6.

Answer (score 10):

Your check should be:

```
if (Attachment != null  && Attachment.Length > 0)
```

First check if the Attachment is null and then lenght, since you are using `&&` that will cause [short-circut evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

[&& Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, but **only evaluates its second operand if necessary**.

Previously you had the condition like: `(Attachment.Length > 0 && Attachment != null)`, since the first condition is accessing the property `Length` and if `Attachment` is null, you end up with the exception, With the modified condition `(Attachment != null  && Attachment.Length > 0)`, it will check for null first and only moves further if `Attachment` is not null.

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks Habib....So much. but can you tell me what a issue with previous one plz

Comment: @SANDEEP, just modified the answer, for why you were getting the exception before

Answer (score 4):

The best if statement in my opinion is this:

```
if(Attachment  is { Length: > 0 })
```

this code check both: null and length of the attachment

Answer (score 0):

Now we could also use:

```
if (Attachment != null  && Attachment.Any())
```

Any() is often easier to understand in a glance for the developer than checking Length() > 0. Also has very little difference with processing speed.

Comment: Yes, but .Any() is not internal method and adds a dependency to System.Linq (LINQ) library. 

LINQ is great, but for this simple action I wouldn't add an extra dependency.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio version `3.4.1`

```
if(Attachment != null)
{
   code here ...
}
```

Comment: The question was for C#. See the tag at bottom... ;-)