# How to handle null or empty value in FileContentResult return type in c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, filecontentresult

I have a method to download files with return type **FileContentResult**

am getting byte array from API and downloading file from that but not getting how to handle if i get null value from api.

```
 public FileContentResult DownloadEID()
 {
   byte[] ContentBody = "api returns byte array";

   return File(ContentBody,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf,"abc.pdf");
 }
```

but how to handle return type if i get null value from api?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a controller first check the status.  A good status should be 200 OK.  Null is probably indicating you did not get the 200.  So instead of check for null check for 200.

Comment: might be this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476267/how-to-check-byte-array-empty-or-not

Comment: Depends what you want the caller to see. I'd be inclined to return a `NotFound` result if there's no file to return.

Comment: Hi @RichardDeeming, yes thats correct but for return type FileContentResult  i dont think it works

Comment: @Surya Change the return type to `ActionResult` (MVC5) / `IActionResult` (ASP.NET Core).

Comment: Thanks @RichardDeeming, i modified some code with return type ActionResult  and its working, Thank You